# Application failed to codesign using XCode 4.6.3 while XCode 5 is installed

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, codesign

A little background;

I have a project that was created using XCode 4.6.3. 
After upgrading 4.6.3 to XCode 5, I was having issues working with the project (iOS7 interface etc) and therefore decided to download the stand alone XCode 4.6.3 from the Apple developer website. 
After downloading, I copied 4.6.3 to ./Applications/Xcode4 with XCode5 still residing in ./Applications/XCode.

The problem;

My project opens and runs fine in 4.6.3 as it had previously done, functioning fine in the simulator and on my device with no issues. However, after completing many successful 'Archive's' (before updating XCode), when I Archive the app for my ad-hoc distribution now, I'm getting the following warning:

```
Validate /Users/ross/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nandf-hkfbmrneltwmpuedrwmfqfimcqbh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/nandf/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/nandf.app
cd /Users/ross/Documents/nandf
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode4.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
/Applications/Xcode4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/ross/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nandf-hkfbmrneltwmpuedrwmfqfimcqbh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/nandf/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/nandf.app

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)Executable=/Users/ross/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nandf-hkfbmrneltwmpuedrwmfqfimcqbh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/nandf/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/nandf.app/nandfcodesign_wrapper-4.1: using Apple CA for profile evaluation/Users/ross/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nandf-hkfbmrneltwmpuedrwmfqfimcqbh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/nandf/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/nandf.app: valid on disk/Users/ross/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nandf-hkfbmrneltwmpuedrwmfqfimcqbh/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/nandf/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/nandf.app: satisfies its Designated Requirementtest-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)codesign_wrapper-4.1: failed to execute codesign(1) - (null
```

Have already checked;

- My provisioning profile is showing as valid inside the XCode Organizer and the appropriate profile is selected for both the Project & Target Code Signing Identities.
- The Project 'Validate Built Project' is set to No for Debug and Yes for Release, the same for Target.

Any further insight into the cause / resolution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hm, it's looking at /Applications/Xcode.app instead of /Applications/Xcode4.app, which is bad.

What happens if you go to (in Xcode 4) Window->Organizer->Projects and delete the derived data from your project, then clean and build?

Comment: I had actually tried renaming XCode4.app to XCode.app to see if that would work, it did not. Original post updated to reflect the current Validation Warning. After deleting the derived data, cleaning and archiving, the Validation Warning still appears.

Comment: Have you tried to use `xcode-select` to select which command line toolset to use?

Comment: So I just ran: 'sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode4.app/Contents/Developer' and re-launched XCode. It is still giving the same Validation Warning.